# What's another way of saying "I failed to mention"

Tags: grammar, synonyms

I failed to mention I faced a similar situation with... I don't like the message I'm presenting

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I strongly encourage you to visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

> I omitted to specify that...
>
> I inadvertently omitted to report that...
>
> One thing I have overlooked/I haven't mentioned is that...
>
> I have forgotten to say that...
>
> Something I missed in here is that...

Answer (score 1):

When adding a comment, simply state '**additionally**' but if this a case in which you are in the process of [rephrasing of an immediately preceding word or statement for the purpose of intensification, emphasis, or justification](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Epanorthosis), it is an **epanorthosis**.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> I should also have {said / referred to / included} the fact that...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give us a little more context information. But from the looks of it you do not want to give a wrong impression by using the word "failed". 
You may substitute it with something like:

I did not include such information as...

or

I omitted the fact that...

Bing dictionary:

o·mit
[ ō mít ]

1.leave somebody or something out: to fail to include or mention somebody or something, either deliberately or accidentally
2.fail to do something: to fail to do something, either deliberately or accidentally

Answer (score 0):

I don't advise it, but you could say "As I have already said before...." and try not to blush.